# Simple Prolog setof

Tags: prolog, logic, prolog-setof

this is simple yet cannot seem to grasp it
I have these "colors"

```
color(blue).
color(red).
color(white).
```

using `setof` I need to get all possible combinations of these colors in a list
It would be great if you can provide a brief explanation. I tried this query

`setof(X,color(X),Colors).` which failed obviously

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you meant this with combinations:

```
?- setof((X,Y), (color(X), color(Y)), ColorsCombined).
ColorsCombined = [ (blue, blue), (blue, green), (blue, red), (green, blue), (green, green), (green, red), (red, blue), (red, green), (..., ...)].
```

Or did you mean the superset?

```
subset([Element|Set], [Element|Subset]):- subset(Set, Subset).
subset([_|Set], Subset):- subset(Set, Subset).
subset([], []).

superset(Set, Superset) :- setof(Subset, subset(Set, Subset), Superset).
```

This is the output:

```
 ?- superset([1,2,3], Superset).
Superset = [[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]].
```

Comment: Thanks, its basically what I wanted!! Just for further understanding I used this query  `setof((X,Y,Z), (color(X), color(Y),color(Z)), ColorsCombined)`. and got three item tupples but I wanted to have a list of lists. e.g ColorsCombined = [(red,red,red),...] and what I wanted is ColorsCombined [[red,red,red],....]                      What do I need to change?

Comment: change the brackets from () to []

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this ?

```
all_permutations(Permutations) :-

    % get all colors into a list
    setof(Color, color(Color), One_Color_List),

    % find all combinations using permutation/2 on One_Color_List
    setof(Permutation, 
       permutation(One_Color_List, Permutation), 
       Permutations).
```

Results:

```
?- all_permutations(X).
X = [[blue, red, white], [blue, white, red], [red, blue, white], [red, white, blue], [white, blue, red], [white, red, blue]].
```

The trick is to get the facts into a list - as you did, then use permutation/2 to generate all permutations of that list.

If that's what you wanted.. wasn't clear...

Comment: Actually yes its what I wanted, Thanks!!